# Scatterplot keeps copying itself

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatterplot that appears below an interactive worldmap with the help of D3. The scatterplot contains data from the country that the user clicked on in the worldmap. The problem is that when the user clicks on another country, the scatterplot of the previous country should disappear. This is not the case unfortunately, the second scatterplot just appears under the first scatterplot. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A part of the code I use for the scatterplot:

```
function ScatterCorruption(dataset, title){

    var xValue = function(d) { return d.GDP;}
    var yValue = function(d) { return d.Variable;}

    // determine parameters
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 200, left: 70},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // formatters for axis and labels
    var currencyFormat = d3.format("0.2f");
    var decimalFormat = d3.format("0.2f");

    // determine x scale
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

    // determine y scale
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    // determine x-axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

    // determine y-axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

    // make svg
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

    console.log(dataset)

    // load in data
    d3.tsv(dataset, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

      // convert data
      data.forEach(function(d) {

        d.GDP = +d.GDP;
        d.Variable = +d.Variable;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call this before rendering a new scatterplot: `d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();` so that your svg is clear again. Alternatively you can also do `d3.select("svg").remove();` and then recreate the svg.